# NullPointerException when attempting to access array of objects

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am writing Java code for a Monopoly game and I am getting a NullPointerException on the line with the SetPlayerName(tempName, numPlayersCounter); method call. This method sets the name of a Player in a Player array. When the program is run, the console says that the value of numPlayersCounter is 1, the length of the Player array playersArr is 3.

```
        sc2.ok1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //middle ok button
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Name ok button pressed");
            System.out.println("Name is:" + sc2.nameField.getText());
            String tempName = sc2.nameField.getText();
            System.out.println("numPlayersCounter value: " + numPlayersCounter);

            SetPlayerName(tempName, numPlayersCounter);
            System.out.println("Player " + numPlayersCounter + "name: " +playersArr[numPlayersCounter].GetName());
            sc2.EnableName(false);
            sc2.EnablePieces(true);


        }
    });
```

The method SetPlayerName is defined as:

```
    public static void SetPlayerName(String n, int id)
    {   playersArr[id].SetName(n);    }
```

and playersArr is declared before the constructor and main as:

```
    protected static Player [] playersArr; //player 0 is the bank
```

In Player.java, the name is set as an empty string in the constructor and the SetName method is defined as:

```
    public void SetName(String n)
    {   name = n;   }
```

I have tried to set the name directly from the actionPerformed method and incrementing a different Player variable. The problem seems to be with accessing the correct array element, but it should be accessing element 1 of an array of length 3.

What do I need to do to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You never initialize your array `playersArr` (so it is `null`).

Comment: _"What do I need to do to fix this?"_  change to something like  `protected static Player [] playersArr = new Player[10];` but I would recommend you to use `ArrayList` instead of `array`

Comment: I initialize it in my constructor and then point playersArr to a new array in a previous actionPerformed method. Sorry I didn't add that before. I will update my question to include this.

Comment: @jdphenix, I was looking at that post earlier and I was not able to use it to my advantage

Comment: then its not `playersArr` null, but `playersArr[id]`

Comment: @DnR initializing when I declare the array is not working either. I will look into the ArrayList.

Comment: @Baby, the value being passed into id is 1 and the length of the array is 3 (according to the console when the program is run), so 1 should be a valid location

Comment: try printing the array content at the same location you print the array length: `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(playersArr));` what is the output?

Comment: I bet your output is `[null, null, null]` . isn't it?

Comment: @Baby you were right! The output is [null, null, null] . Now I need to find out why        playersArr = new Player[numPlayers+1];
dosen't initialize 3 new Player objects.

Comment: I have no default constructor...

Comment: have you tried just `new Player()`?. you don't have to define a default constructor. default constructor is exist by default

Comment: I changed the constructor to a default constructor (parameters were not necessary) and Gary posted the answer I was looking for. Thank you too, Baby. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reason:

You have an empty array list, i.e., `playerArr[0] = null;` and your `SetPlayerName` method references `playerArr[id]` which contains a `null` pointer.

### Fix:

You need to add `Player` objects to your `playerArr` before trying to use them, try this:

```
playerArr[numPlayersCounter] = new Player();
SetPlayerName(tempName, numPlayersCounter);
```

You should also initiate the `playerArr` too, with 3 elements...:

```
protected static Player[] playerArr = new Player[3];
```

Comment: That is exactly what needed to happen (with the exception of playerArr being playersArr , with an s). Thank you very much @gary-read

Answer (score 0):

From what is given, you have not initialized your `playersArr` array. On the line:

```
protected static Player [] playersArr;
```

or anytime because you call the SetPlayerName() method you need to initialize it.  For example:

```
protected static Player [] playersArr = new Player[]{/*Stuff in array*/};
```

Comment: Make sure you do not have anything in your code setting playerArr to null and can you show me what you have changed?

Comment: Turns out the array was initialized, but the individual Player objects were not. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the Player?

```
playersArr[numPlayersCounter] = new Player();
```

and then

```
SetPlayerName(tempName, numPlayersCounter);
```

Comment: That was the problem. I chose Gary's answer though because he had answered earlier.  Thank you for your help.